# Find members with consecutive entries

Tags: postgresql, date, postgresql-8.2

I need to find all members in the database with data on 7 or more consecutive days. The table is set up as member_id and data_date. There are duplicate member_ids for each day that there is data.

I found some answers using MySQL that involved `datediff` or `dateadd`, but I am not sure how to do this in PostgreSQL 8.2.15. Below is an example of what the table looks like, but with many more rows.

```
+------------+------------+
| member_id  |  data_date |
+------------+------------+
|    0000001 | 2018-04-10 |
|    0000005 | 2018-04-16 |
|    0000001 | 2018-04-11 |
|    0000002 | 2018-04-12 |
|    0000003 | 2018-04-13 |
|    0000004 | 2018-04-12 |
|    0000005 | 2018-04-15 |
|    0000003 | 2018-04-19 |
|    0000002 | 2018-04-17 |
|    0000001 | 2018-04-18 |
|    0000005 | 2018-04-10 |
|    0000002 | 2018-04-18 |
|    0000001 | 2018-04-08 |
|    0000002 | 2018-04-03 |
|    0000003 | 2018-04-02 |
|    0000004 | 2018-04-14 |
|    0000005 | 2018-04-15 |
|    0000003 | 2018-04-16 |
|    0000002 | 2018-04-19 |
|    0000001 | 2018-04-14 |
+------------+------------+
```

`(member_id, data_date)` is defined `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple query should work in your outdated version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT member_id
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 USING (member_id)
JOIN   tbl t3 USING (member_id)
JOIN   tbl t4 USING (member_id)
JOIN   tbl t5 USING (member_id)
JOIN   tbl t6 USING (member_id)
JOIN   tbl t7 USING (member_id)
WHERE  t2.data_date = t1.data_date + 1
AND    t3.data_date = t1.data_date + 2
AND    t4.data_date = t1.data_date + 3
AND    t5.data_date = t1.data_date + 4
AND    t6.data_date = t1.data_date + 5
AND    t7.data_date = t1.data_date + 6;
```

In Postgres, you can just add `integer` to a `date` to get the next day.

And probably fast, too - as long as you don't have much longer streaks of entries producing many dupes in the first step.

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT member_id
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 USING (member_id)
WHERE  t2.data_date BETWEEN t1.data_date + 1
                        AND t1.data_date + 6
GROUP  BY t1.member_id, t1.date
HAVING count(*) = 6;
```

Update to a current version of Postgres at the earliest opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Your version is [very antiquated and insecure. For reference 8.2 was last supported in 2011. It was released in 2006.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) It lacks

- tstz ranges
- window functions
- lateral joins

Moreover, we can't easily configure your setup to test our queries. Upgrade your version PostgreSQL; if you find that difficult to do, consider seeking out a consultant.

I think what you want is something like

```
SELECT member_id, t2.date, count(*)
FROM t AS t1
CROSS JOIN t AS t2
  ON ( member_id )
WHERE t1.date_date BETWEEN t2.date AND t2.date_date + '7 days
GROUP BY member_id, t2.date
HAVING count(*) >= 7;
```

But I can't test it and you didn't provide `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements.